# What's the best way to init class attribute in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are two methods:

**1:**

```
def get(params):
    res = "do_something"
    return res

class A():
    a = get(params)

a=A()
```

**2:**

```
class A():
    a = ""

    @classmethod
    def Init(cls,params):
        res = "do_something"
        cls.a = res

a=A()
a.Init()
```

I don't know how to choose.Or is there something better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class attributes are supposed to be static properties that are shared among all the instances and don't change values (eg, `num_sides` for all `Square` instances). So, it's a good policy to initialize them once, on class level.

The `classmethod` on the other hand  is mainly supposed to be used for alternative constructors. Although you get access to the class, your main objective is initializing an instance. Assigning a class attribute in a such function is confusing to the reader. Additionally, it initialises the value every time this constructor is called.

Overall, the first method is better.